# M2doc Sirius session programmatically

Tags: m2doc

I'm tried to generate document template using m2doc.
In my template I want to use some sirius services.

It'works manually. I want to do it programmatically in a custom service.

Can i generate document with sirius service directly from the DocumentTemplate without generation?
How can I set the “SiriusSession” option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I use a Generation (genconf file)and set the sirius session like this :

```
 final Option option = GenconfUtils.getOrCreateOption(generation, M2DocSiriusUtils.SIRIUS_SESSION_OPTION);
    //ressource of representation
    option.setValue("../test/representations.aird");
    generation.getOptions().add(option);
```

Comment: You can also have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64597460/trouble-using-m2doc-core-generation-api-and-siriusservices)