# Trouble using M2Doc core generation API and SiriusServices

Tags: m2doc

I am trying to generate documentation using the core generation API (as described here https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/3.1.0/index.html#core-generation-api). But I have the following error:
Couldn't find the 'isRepresentationDescriptionName()' service.
(It works fine when I use the genconf not programmatically).

I tried to add the SiriusServices using SiriusServiceConfigurator, but didn't manage to solve this issue.

Or maybe is it because I didn't add the SiriusSession option that refers to the .aird file?

I have looked at how new services are added in the newEnvironmentWithDefaultServices work but it is seems not applicable for SiriusServices.

```
    final IQueryEnvironment queryEnvironment = org.eclipse.acceleo.query.runtime.Query
            .newEnvironmentWithDefaultServices(null);

    final Monitor monitor = new BasicMonitor.Printing(System.out);
    final ResourceSet resourceSetForModels = session.getTransactionalEditingDomain().getResourceSet();

    resourceSetForModels.createResource(modelUri);
    try (DocumentTemplate template = M2DocUtils.parse(resourceSetForModels.getURIConverter(), templateURI,
            queryEnvironment, classProvider, monitor)) {

        final Map<String, Object> variable = new HashMap<>();
                M2DocUtils.generate(template, queryEnvironment, variable, resourceSetForModels, outputURI, monitor);
            ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Sirius related services need the Sirius Session. The Session is initialized using the SiriusSession option in the .genconf file. It should be set to an URI referencing the .aird file. In the class [M2DocUtils](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/master/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/util/M2DocUtils.java) you have several methods to create an IQueryEnvironment that take a Map of String where you can add the SiriusSession option, for instance:

```
M2DocUtils.getQueryEnvironment(ResourceSet, URI, Map<String, String>)
```

Note that your code needs to be ran inside of Eclipse, not a standalone java program.